# Testing and Continuous Integration architecture approach using nUnit and FitNesse

Tags: .net, testing, nunit, teamcity, fitnesse

I'm looking for opinions and thoughts surrounding testing and Continuous Integration using nUnit and/or FitNesse.

We develop applications, both windows and web with .net and are using TeamCity for continuous integration

I'm wondering what is the best way (and tools) to go about testing the various layers of our applications.

For example, should I be using FitNesse for 
  UA Testing
  Stored Procedure Testing
and nUnit for
  c# Unit Testin

Should I be using FitNesse to test everything?
Can I run FitNesse tests from TeamCity and see the output?

Thanks for any help and direction :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're using nUnit for unit testing and FitNesse for story testing (aka acceptance testing, integration testing, etc). We don't use stored procedures but dbFit is a useful add-on to FitNesse that can do that. We use TeamCity to execute the nUnit and FitNesse tests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've never tested stored procs and was wondering where they fit in the process.

Comment: how did you run FitNesse from TeamCity? Do you use something like a bat file and how do you get teamcity to fail if a test fails? Thanks for your help and info

Answer (score 3):

Regarding using Fitnesse to test everything:

Unit testing is about *building the code right*. And it is done best by the xUnit frameworks like JUnit and Nunit.

Acceptance tests are about *building the right code*. And this is where Fitnesse excels. Both types of tests are needed and both kinds of frameworks make your life easier in carrying out these tests.

Look here for more on this: http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AcceptanceTests

Can I run FitNesse tests from TeamCity and see the output?

Yes you can. Teamcity has a commandline runner in addition to specific runners, so you must be able to run anything that runs from a console and see the output. Also, if you were asking about more advanced things like test reports integration with Teamcity, have a look at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD3/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-servMsgs whereby you can easily update the test status etc even while the build is running.